# Eloquent Relationships : Two pivot tables to store my order's product's features data

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, pivot-table

I am creating an web application in Slim 3. I have installed the Laravel's Eloquent Package.

In my application, i have  products on which there are some free features and some paid features. someone can select  the paid features on there own. means he can set what paid feature of that product he want and which he don't.

OK. Till now i am able to get my product into the cart by storing the product into the session.

Then i wanted to store all the products into the cart with there selected paid features.

Product Model

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public $quantity = null;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'desciption',
        'price',
        'image',
        'stock',

    ];



    public function features()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'feature_product')->withPivot('quantity');
    }    


}
```

My Feature Model:

```
    class Feature extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'features';
    public $quantity = null;
    protected $fillable = [
       'body',
       'paid' 

    ];
}
```

Order Model

```
    class Order extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'orders';

    protected $fillable = [
        'hash',
        'total',
        'paid',
        'address_id',
        'user_id',
        'request_id'

    ];
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
    }
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'orders_products')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
    public function payment()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Payment::class);
    }





}
```

Order Controller : Create Function which will fire when i check out of the cart.

```
public function create(Request $request,Response $response)
    {  
        //basket->all gives me the array of objects of products in the cart
        $allItems = $this->basket->all();

        //getQuantities gives the array of the quantities of respective product in the cart.
        $this->order->products()->saveMany($allItems,$this->getQuantities($allItems));

        //need to know can i save feature that the use selected while adding the product into the cart .
    }
```

with this i am also able to fetch the array of object of selected features some how.

so, as you can see till now iam able to save the products into the pivot table "orders_products" with respective quantities.

but how can i save the features that user have selected before adding the feature into the cart into a table.

my approach is to creating a new pivot or whatever so that i can able to store the feature id of the selected paid feature  with  respective to the id of entry of product in to the pivot "orders_products".

I don't how i do it. I have already scratched all my head.
Please help. it would be a great favour to me.

My table schema:
[Tables Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n3aD.png)